# How to get attribute from tricky elements with Cheerio?

Tags: node.js, cheerio

Hi im trying to extract some info from a webpage and its a bit tricky. 
The elements that I need info from looks like this;

```
<div id="1449822" class="match_line score_row other_match e_true " data-
cntr="0" data-parent-competition="A-LEAGUE" data-note="Venue: Etihad Stadium. 
Turf: Natural. Capacity: 56,347. Distance: 1,667km. Sidelined Players: 
MELBOURNE VICTORY - AUSTIN MITCHELL, DENG THOMAS, NIGRO STEFAN (Injured). 
BRISBANE ROAR FC - BROWN COREY, DE VERE LUKE, O TOOLE CONNOR, THEO MICHAEL, 
CALETTI JOE, D AGOSTINO NICHOLAS (Injured)." data-competition-name="A-LEAGUE" 
data-league-type="LEAGUE" data-season="2017/2018" data-statustype="sched" 
data-ko="09:50" data-home-team="MELBOURNE VICTORY" data-away-team="BRISBANE 
ROAR FC" data-league-sort="11" data-correction="0" data-matchday="2018-02-09" 
data-game-status="Sched" data-league-code="41256" data-league-name="A-LEAGUE" 
data-country-name="AUSTRALIA" data-league-round="20" data-league-short="AL" 
data-home-id="28529" data-away-id="28531" data-ftr="false">
```

Im especially interested whats inside:

```
 data-season= 
 data-note=
 data-league-name=
 data-country-name=
 data-home-team=
 data-Away-team=
```

But im unsure how to get this info here is what I have tried

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  request('http://www.xscores.com/soccer', function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);
      var list_items = "";

      $('div.match_line.score_row.other_match.e_true').each(function (i, element) {
        var a = $(this).text();
        list_items += "<li>" + a + "</li>";
      });

      var html = "<ul>" + list_items + "</ul>"
      res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
      });
      res.end(html);
    }
  });
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server is running at http://178.62.253.206:8080/');
```

However it looks like the above code does not fetch what is inside this element but rather it fetches info from all div elements that is under this , Here is what my code returned: http://178.62.253.206:8080/

```
10:50 SCH SHOW GAMES FROM AUSTRALIA AL MELBOURNE VICTORY 5 Â  Â  BRISBANE 
ROAR FC 7 Â  Â  Match Details
```

Any help with this matter would be much appreciated

frederik

Comment: Because you are fetching text from inside the elements. You need to read the attributes, so instead of `$(this).text()`, try `element.attr('data-season')` and so on.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply . I just updated the title for this question after reading trough google for about an hour or so. Could you please specify or give an example as my knowledge is quite limited at this point,

Comment: I tried like this: var a = element.attr('data-season'); But that did not work

Comment: Boom I got it :) Much appreciated for pointing me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const divElement = `your_div_element`;
const $ = cheerio.load(divElement);

$(divElement).map((index, element) => {
    const attributes = element.attribs;
    Object.keys(attributes).map(key => {
        console.log(key, ': ', attributes[key]);
    })
});
```

I have created this simple script which will help you get all the attribute names and their values, you can filter out the one that you are interested in.